# Slide show sobrepondo o menu

Tags: html, css

Estou com um problema com meu slide shoqw ele ta sobrepondo o menu.

segue o codigo:
https://jsfiddle.net/mgodq202/

Comment: Cria um exemplo do problema que seja possivel reproduzirmos no https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: ok vou criar, mas o slide tem 2 arquivos em java script e um com link, como eu faria?

Comment: Use `ul li { list-style: none;}` na sua lista para tirar os pontos, e coloque `z-index: 9999;` na sua NavBar. Se não der certo tente reproduzir sua página em algum repositório, pq do jeito que está na pergunta não da pra simular o erro...

Comment: ok vou testar aq agora

Comment: o z-index funcionou, mas não consegui tirar os pontos com ul li .

Comment: vou fazer oq vc falou e edito a pagina .

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mgodq202/ o único problema q permanece agr é aparecer os numero 1 2 3 e os pts  3 pontos . . .

Answer (score 1):

Dá uma lida nessas documentações, tem exemplos:

Para o problema de sobreposição:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Para remover o ponto:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/list-style

Para substituir a imagem por texto basta substituir a img por div e colocar o texto dentro, e setar os text-align, white-space e outros parametros css ...

Se estiver começando agora, sugiro utilizar algo pronto para Slider para evitar gambiarras: https://imasters.com.br/front-end/jquery/os-14-melhores-plugins-de-image-slider-em-jquery/?trace=1519021197&source=single

Comment: eu já tentei por slide prontos assim e só deu ruim kkk esse foi o único q deu certo eu vi um tutorial e consegui fzr .

Comment: eu editei o topico se tiver como da uma olhada

Comment: eu consegui remover os pontos só não estou conseguindo remover os numeros.

Comment: se tiver como da uma ajuda :x

Comment: Eu fiz um slider simples por contra própria , mas é para texto
https://portaldoprofessor.fct.unesp.br/projetos/cadilag/login.php

Comment: Clica no slider com o botão direito e usa o inspecionar elemento para ver o html do slider. É bem simples e nem precisa de ul e li.

Comment: #slide > div > div > ol > li:nth-child(3) > a fala q está nessa linha, mas eu não acho ela no html nem no css.

Comment: #slide > div > div > ol > li:nth-child(2) > a

Comment: fala q está dentro dos li                                                                                               <li>
    <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="">
   
   </li>

   <li>
    <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="">
   </li>

   <li>
    <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="">
 
   </li>, mas eu não acho nenhuuma class nem no html nem no css ..

Comment: os números estão vindo do alt='123', não?

Comment: não não aqueles ali eu q botei nos alt.

Comment: Eu testei sem e ficou a mesma coisa eu tou achando q o problema está na script .

Comment: Acho q está vindo de lá esses numeros ..